# Migrate (on-prem) SQL data to Azure with Databricks (JDBC)

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Is it possible to use the JDBC connector https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html in order to get data from local SQL server. (and export it to delta lake)

Using:

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "password" : jdbcPassword,
  "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}
```

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?  Your question asks about SQL Server but you're using a MySql jdbc url.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective if you have MySql or SQL Server, Databricks driver supports both as outlined in the article you linked.
From the perspective of access to on-prem - the answer is yes, however Databricks must be able to connect to it. Usually this will mean deploying your Databricks clusters into your VNET which has access to your on-prem resources, e.g. [following the guidance here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject)

Alternatively you could use Azure Data Factory self-hosted integration runtime to move the data to a staging/"Bronze" storage in the cloud and pick it up with a Databricks task to move it to a Delta table.

Comment: I double on moving data instead of using JDBC